# Microchip TCP client talking to Microchip TCP server

Tags: curl, tcp, server, client, microchip

I've researched over and over, and this is my first question to the site I love. I have a Microchip based server/client, asking for a web page from another Microchip TCP server, of same version.

I have one development board request a web page from another development board, and via wire shark, can see the communications, and see that only ARP broadcasting is used from the GenericTCPClient.c code. It works, but wire shark communications does NOT look the same as if CURL, or a generic web browser requested the same information.

Either in front of my face, or Microchip code (client) does not support what I think it should. I have written FTP and email programs from scratch back in the college days from reading the RFC's, so no stranger to wanting and needing to know about the low level requests through sockets if that's what it takes.

Plus, if web page has username and password... i.e. http://admin:password@192.168.1.10/page.htm... The microchip client doesn't seem to support that, unless I am not seeing the light.

simple example from demo GenericTCPClient.c as follows if need to change low level commands.

```
        // Place the application protocol data into the transmit buffer.  For this 
        // example, we are connected to an HTTP server, so we'll send an HTTP GET 
        // request.
        TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"GET ");
        TCPPutROMString(MySocket, RemoteURL);
        TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ");
        TCPPutString(MySocket, ServerName);
        TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)"\r\n\r\n");

        // Send the packet
        TCPFlush(MySocket);
        GenericTCPExampleState++;
```

I've used the debug verbose feature using CURL and seen what it sent, and also seen communications via wireshark, and same using generic browser, but can not seem to get similar results, using same low level commands seen from CURL, inside the GenericTCpCLient.c.

So using commands captured via CURL, or a generic web browser, as commands for "GET" for grabbing a web page from a Microchip TCP client, to a Microchip, server, does not show same results.

GenericTCPClient.c just uses ARP broadcast, but want to use same commands that CURL would use.

Am I missing something? CURL works awesome, but trying to use same commands within GenericTCPClient.c does not seem to produce the same results... especially is user and password is used in URL.

So in a nut shell... Microchip GenericTCPCLient.c, requesting a WEB page from a Microchip TCP server, Wireshark shows the ARP broadcasting, while CURL and any web browser shows the right way.

Thanks for any feedback or pointers to other posts of this nature. This is my fav place when I get stumped.

Comment: Aren't you horribly mixing up http and tcp/ip ?

Comment: It is a possibility. When using TCPPutROMString(MySocket, (ROM BYTE*)" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "); and the rest of what I thought was needed, from CURL in debug verbose mode, I don't seem to be getting the same results from using wireshark. Wireshark shows different color coded traffic from using CURL to load a web page, then using same commands in the Microchip TCPClient, to a Microchip TCPServer. Been out on medical leave to don't have all tools in front of me till next week to show CURL response from wireshark, compared, to Microchip TCPClient response from Wireshark.

Comment: Basically I used line by line of what CURL responded with in debug mode, and input same commands used in Microchip TCPClient code. And got different results traffic wise from wireshark.

Comment: What results are you seeing? What results are you expecting? Telling us the results are "different" is not really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to see the Ethernet traffic from one embedded device to another is difficult with switches.  I have an Ethernet Hub on my desk for this reason.  A switch will route the traffic to only the specific port that has the end device; a hub will duplicate all the data on all the ports.

The reason the PC (and Wireshark) can see the ARP broadcast is because it is a broadcast.  The switch is sending that packet to all the ports.  If the TCP Server is responding, it is responding directly to the TCP Client, bypassing the PC (and Wireshark).

My suggestion is to install a web server on the PC.  Debug the TCP Client trying to get a page from the PC.  You can run Wireshark and it will show all the interaction.

Next debug the TCP Server using the PC's web browser.  Again, Wireshark will be able to show all the data.

Finally, debug the communication between the 2 embedded devices.

The username and password is probably covered by the HTTPHeaderParseAuthorization function.  Look for HTTP_USE_AUTHENTICATION.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved...
After reading RFC 1945 Section 11.1, I found out that I needed to encode the "username:password" to base 64. And then provide and extra argument to the socket. I never knew that until further research. Was thinking I needed to pass the user:pass in the URL, (like in a web browser, or cURL command line) not as an extra argument to the socket.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1
I.e. htttp://user:pass@192.168.1.X/webpage.htm

TCPPutROMString(MySocket,(ROM BYTE*)"Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==");
The Auth code was generated from the Apple open source base_64 conversion I found from another thread by passing in the string "username:password" and getting the base64 result to pass into the socket.
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-452/CommonUtilitiesLib/base64.c

As for the results being different from using cURL, or a web browser. They both used TCP commands that showed up green in wireshark. Using the Microchip client shows up as an ARP broadcast from client ip address to server ip address. i.e. 192.168.1.11 to 192.168.1.10 broadcast.